# Launch JVM process from a Java application use Runtime.exec?

Tags: java, process, launch

I want to be able to launch a Java server process from an existing java application and monitor the stdoutput and stderror and redirect that output to a file.  Is the best approach to use 'Runtime.exec' and treat the app like any other OS process or is there something more suited for new JVMs.

This is on Java 1.5

Comment: If you do decide to use Runtime, read ["When Runtime.exec Won't..."](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html)

Comment: Yes, having a means to tell the JVM to execute a new JVM that ran a given class `main()` method would be nice. I guess that would only be acceptable if the new JVM used the current class-loader, otherwise which class implementations were used would be too unpredictable. But that would be very hard, perhaps impossible, because of the need to prevent a process starting the JVM with a trojan class-loader.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of `Runtime`, you should probably use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), though I don't know if something else is even more appropriate in your case (running a Java process in particular).

Comment: ProcessBuilder is exactly the tool for this purpose. You can easily hook the out/err of the process and even redirect the err to out so you don't have to monitor two streams (unless you want to). You will have to write the stream I/O code yourself ... see BufferedInputReader.

Comment: And what if this external process hangs, process.destroy will never be able to kill it, in linux you can send a SIGINT but then it will kill the whole program not just this process, launching something which is not tested, might be on the safe side to launch in altogether a new process unless there is a way to kill this particular process. or if there is then tell me, i laucnh e.g nslookup and then there is no way to kill it, (except the quit) so how can you really kill the process if it hangs??

Answer (score 12):

I know I am late in this thread, but in case someone needs it, in my experience, it is easier to use ANT to launch a Java application. This has the benefit of being platform independent. Here is a sample class that does that:

```
package com.trilliantnetworks.scheduler.quartz.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException;
import org.apache.tools.ant.DefaultLogger;
import org.apache.tools.ant.DemuxOutputStream;
import org.apache.tools.ant.Project;
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Echo;
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java;
import org.apache.tools.ant.types.Path;

public class MyLaunchTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Project project = new Project();
    project.setBaseDir(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
    project.init();
    DefaultLogger logger = new DefaultLogger();
    project.addBuildListener(logger);
    logger.setOutputPrintStream(System.out);
    logger.setErrorPrintStream(System.err);
    logger.setMessageOutputLevel(Project.MSG_INFO);
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new DemuxOutputStream(project, false)));
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(new DemuxOutputStream(project, true)));
    project.fireBuildStarted();

    System.out.println("running");
    Throwable caught = null;
    try {
        Echo echo = new Echo();
        echo.setTaskName("Echo");
        echo.setProject(project);
        echo.init();
        echo.setMessage("Launching Some Class");
        echo.execute();

        Java javaTask = new Java();
        javaTask.setTaskName("runjava");
        javaTask.setProject(project);
        javaTask.setFork(true);
        javaTask.setFailonerror(true);
        javaTask.setClassname(MyClassToLaunch.class.getName());
        Path path = new Path(project, new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/classes").getAbsolutePath());
        javaTask.setClasspath(path);
        javaTask.init();
        int ret = javaTask.executeJava();
        System.out.println("java task return code: " + ret);

    } catch (BuildException e) {
        caught = e;
    }
    project.log("finished");
    project.fireBuildFinished(caught);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried something similar to this but it always hang when it reach project.init(). It doesn't produce any error but just won't move from that line. Any comment on that?

Comment: Thanks for the idea with Ant to be platform-independent. Needed to run a executable-jar from within SoapUI which also has to run on a CI later.

Comment: you have to install apache ant and need to set "ANT_HOME" as a path variable. see https://www.mkyong.com/ant/how-to-install-apache-ant-on-windows/