# Runtime class in java

Tags: java, runtime, runtime.exec

How to execute a java program with the help of Runtime.getRuntime().exec().
For example we shall have the java file path as c:/java/abc.java. Please help me with the code.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that abc.java contains a main method that you want to execute:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac c:\java\abc.java -d c:\java\")
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java c:\java\abc")
```

Comment: CreateProcess: c:\j2sdk1.4.0\bin\helloworld error=2
This is the runtime exception message

Comment: That doesn't really give a whole lot to go off of. Can you edit your question to include a simple helloworld file and the whole stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

Do not forget that:

- you may need to read stdout/stderr of a java program
- you may have to set/update environment variable and PATH before executing your java command

  CreateProcess: c:\j2sdk1.4.0\bin\helloworld error=2

means Win32's `CreateProcess` returns a 2 as error code when it cannot find the command you specify; more specifically, when the command does not refer to an executable file on its lookup path.

Look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236737#236873) for a more complete "`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`" code, and also to [this snippet](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6335).

This code creates a shell (as in `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /K")`), in which you write on `sdtin` whatever command you want to execute.

The interest of this approach is to reuse the shell process to benefit from a previous command: it you execute a '`cd`', then execute a '`dir`', the latter command would display the content of the directory referenced by the `cd` command.

The same would be true for `PATH` settings, just before using `javac` or `java`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [ProcessBuilder](http://java.sun.com/developer/JDCTechTips/2005/tt0727.html#2) instead of Runtime. Basic usage is like:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
```

You will find more code under the link above. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480433/launch-jvm-process-from-a-java-application-use-runtime-exec/480463#480463).

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want a Java program to run another Java program. [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419715/sample-java-code-to-run-bat-file-periodically) might be helpful, in that case.

Answer (score 1):

```
String path1 = "f://" + File.separator+username+File.separator+progName; 
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
String command = "javac -classpath " + path + " " + path1;
System.out.println(command);
Process process = runtime.exec(command);
InputStream error = process.getErrorStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the excellent resource which used to be called javaalmanac.

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/Exec.html

```
try {
    // Execute a command with an argument that contains a space
    String[] commands = new String[]{"grep", "hello world", "/tmp/f.txt"};
    commands = new String[]{"grep", "hello world", "c:\\Documents and Settings\\f.txt"};
    Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
 } catch (IOException e) {
 }
```