# How to parse strings which have operators into integers?

Tags: java, android, string, parsing, integer

I'll make my question to the point. I have a string with some value and operators. Let's take an example of

4 * 24 + Math.sqrt(36) - 5

So if I do `Integer.parseInt()` it crashed. On further search I found out that I have to use a parser. But they were for command line java whereas mine is in android.

So my question is how do I convert this string "4 * 24 + Math.sqrt(36) - 5" into an integer which calculates the result? Also will this method include the `Math.sqrt ()` function?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**

In response to hacker13ua

When I try your MAVEN method I get this error. Any Idea Why?

Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; regionStart=0; regionLength=3

My Code:

```
final String foo = "4 * 24 + Math.sqrt(36) - 5";
                    Object i = MVEL.eval(foo);
                    String in = i.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(in).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And this is in my gradle build file

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'org.mvel:mvel2:2.2.7.Final'
```

}

Thanks

Comment: please check this link...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661634/execute-java-code-in-java Hope it helps you

Comment: You could try and see if you get any of the common expression languages to run on Android; start with [Unified EL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Expression_Language) for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript engine.

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws ScriptException
    {
        final ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        final ScriptEngine engine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("javascript");
        final String foo = "4 * 24 + Math.sqrt(36) - 5";
        System.out.println(engine.eval(foo));
    }
}
```

Or you can use MVEL.
Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mvel</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvel2</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Your code:

```
import org.mvel2.MVEL;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final String foo = "4 * 24 + Math.sqrt(36) - 5";
        System.out.println(MVEL.eval(foo));
    }
}
```

Comment: System.println Is command line java.  However for the maven one 1 need my pc. I'm on travel and thus am using an ide on phone. Give me a couple of days and I'll reply to the maven answer. However the first part I believe is meant for command line. I saw this answer to another question and I couldn't import the classes. That's why

Comment: Please see my edits above. Also how do you use the javax method. Do I have to add some API. If so how?