# Execute external application from Java or run bat file

Tags: java, batch-file, command

I have an java program that runs external programs executing commandline parameters. After making some searches I found that some people are running .bat files for doing that.
Which is best way for this case?

- Execute command
- Execute bat file

Also I wonder anybody that experienced about running external applications from java,
which problems they come up and are there any unsolvable problems ?

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506154/runtime-class-in-java  and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480433/launch-jvm-process-from-a-java-application-use-runtime-exec/480463#480463

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the apache exec library. 
http://commons.apache.org/exec/

It tries to solve the issues mentioned here:
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

The article describes all the traps that Runtime.exec() throws at you..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the exec method

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myFile.exe");
```

If you want to wait for it to finish you can do

```
p.waitFor();
```