# java out of memory error when executing a swing client

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory

My executable swing client throws out of memory exception when executed from a remote machine. However, executing the client from command line (increasing the heap space) using the following command works.

```
java -XMx128m -Xms128m -jar myclient.jar
```

I do not want the remote users use my client through command line as shown above. So, can I set this heap space while building the executable? I am using Eclipse's Fat Jar Plug-In to create  my executable jar.

Also, is there a way to setup a default value for java heap space for client machines(Windows/Mac/Linux)?

Answer (score 2):

While I do not know of a way to set a default in the individual OS, I can tell you that the command line is the only place for the -X commands to go.  The way we got around that on our project was to give them an installer for windows, or to build them scripts for a particular operating system.  For the installer, we used NSIS, which seemed to work really well.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a standard way to specify memory settings from *within* the application; java needs to start up with the correct settings. The jar file, with manifest, is loaded by java, which has started by then.

You could however use an installer, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676415/how-do-i-allow-the-user-to-easily-choose-how-much-memory-to-allocate-in-a-java-sw) which suggests [NCIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). You can also go for a link (on windows) or a bat file / shell script on Windows. Or perhaps the kind of starter Nexus uses. I did some googling and found [JSW](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html).

So, in summary, your options seem to be:

- an installer like [NCIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)
- a wrapper like [JSW](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html)
- shell script and bat file
- a link file or some such (conceptually similar to script/bat file)

I think I would start with looking at [JSW](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html) as some well-known software like Nexus seems to use that. I don't know whether it works well with desktop apps though. But try and and you'll find out :)

Answer (score 2):

you could also use a wrapper like [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/index.html) which will make an executable for most OS:es and allows you to specify VM options

Answer (score 2):

**Mac OS X**: The articles [*Bringing your Java Application to Mac OS X Part 1*](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaLP/JavaToMac/), [Part 2](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaLP/JavaToMac2/) and [Part 3](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaLP/JavaToMac3/) illustrate how to embed a JAR in a Mac OS application bundle. You can specify run time parameters in the application's property list `Info.plist`, as discussed in [*Java Info.plist Key Reference for Mac OS X*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Reference/Java_InfoplistRef/Java_InfoplistRef.pdf).

Comment: @aperkins: You're welcome! A Mac application is just a directory whose name ends in `.app`. You can even build it with `ant: http://robotchase.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/robotchase/trunk/build.xml?revision=66&view=markup

Comment: it's funny, because I knew that, I had just never thought about doing it that way.  Amazing how the brain misses those obvious connections sometimes.