# How to execute Ant task in another thread

Tags: java, ant

My ant has two target A and B, target A copies a bunch of files to a location, and target checks the copied files in that location.

The problem is that, A needs sometime to complete its execution, but B should wait either blindly (e.g., 30 seconds) or wisely (e.g., check a var/property indicating the finish of task A) to continue its process.

I tried both sleep and wait, but it seems that both of them block the whole thread, so during the wait of target "execute_task", target A is also blocked, so the file copy is in sleep/wait mode.

How should I process, to let target A continues its copy mission, and hold B to wait for a while till A is complete?

thanks a lot!

```
<target name="execute_task">

    <antcall target="A_copy_files"></antcall>
    <antcall target="B_exam_files" ></antcall>

    <waitfor maxwait="30" maxwaitunit="second" timeoutproperty="signal_build_timeout1">
        <istrue value="${set_for_deploy_done}"/>
    </waitfor>
    <antcall target="B_exam_files" ></antcall>

</target>
```

Comment: with fork tag check the doc

Comment: It seems to me you don't want parallel threads at all, but sequential execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you checked this thread

[Run ant from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733684/run-ant-from-java)

http://thilosdevblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/calling-an-ant-target-via-java/

you can use the following to start another thread in java

[Java: How to run thread separately from main program/class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005350/java-how-to-run-thread-separately-from-main-program-class)