# Java: How to open the execution of new Thread in separate command window from Main Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to start the execution of new Thread in separate command window without affecting the execution of main Thread.

I have something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  NewThread n = new NewThread();
  Thread t = new Thread(n);
  t.start(); //Here I want to display the execution of t in separate command prompt.

}

class NewThread implements Runnable{
 public void run(){
  //....
 }
}
```

Can I do it using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() ? Please Help..Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How to run thread separately from main program/class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005350/java-how-to-run-thread-separately-from-main-program-class)

Comment: opening a new command window would be OS specific. Are you ok with that? If so then what OS are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by "without affecting the execution of main Thread"? Are you trying to launch two processes?

Comment: "without affecting the execution of main Thread" in the sense that my main program should run separately in one command prompt and the new thread should run in another. I mean, I should be able to see the execution in two separate command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch `/bin/sh` as a separate process using [Runtime.exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29). If you want to communicate with that child process, use ProcessBuilder. Read answers to [java-process-with-input-output-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream).

Comment: But How shall I display its output in another terminal?

Comment: hmm bin/sh is not sufficient... you have to launch `gnome-terminal -e command` where command is a program which communicates with the parent process some way. Looks like `gnome-terminal` does not provide access to its `stdin` to the commands it starts.

Comment: I think java has limitation here. It should provide the ease to execute threads separately. May Be I will try this one. Lets see. Thanks Alexei.

Answer (score 1):

Use Swing and create a window with text area inside, like in [java-swing-programming-buffered](http://www.prasannatech.net/2008/08/java-swing-programming-buffered.html). This way you need not to launch external processes.

Comment: Thanks..That could be one approach. But sorry I've limitation, Can't use GUI to display the output.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `setDaemon()` method to change the `Thread` daemon properties.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Why? as i understand Question was how Create a daemon from simple thread in java, And this thread mustn't die after main end execute. so  He need create a Daemon.

Comment: Not only did you misunderstand the question, but your understanding of what Thread.setDaemon() does seems to be wrong, too. You should probably read the javadocs for that.