# How to launch an independent java class from another class?

Tags: java, process, jvm, classloader

I need a "main" class that creates other independent class instances. They are independent in that they have their own console and if i close 1 the others don't close.

example: i have these 2 classes

```
public class Class1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Class1();
    }

    Class1() {
        System.out.println("class1");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc.next(); // just to stop runtime from exiting. it suspends it
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Class2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Class2();
    }

    Class2() {
        System.out.println("class2");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc.next();  // just to stop runtime from exiting. it suspends it
    }
}
```

If I launch each one from my IDE I get what I want. But now i want to get the same only with launching class2 from class1 (actually many class 2 from class 1 but getting 1 will get me the others). I tried with a class loader but it doesn't work just shares the same console and closing 1 closes the other. Or I did it wrong.

```
Class1() {
    System.out.println("class1");
    try {
        Class<?> c = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("test.Class2");
        c.newInstance();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    sc.next();
}
```

I don't care if i call the constructor of class 2 or its main method as long as it works. but i found out that calling main from 1 class isn't special like when the class loader does it when launching.

I don;t know if i need a new process, a new VM or a new class loader because i don't know how a console is shared and actually i don't think i know the differences. I know that system exit will exit the VM so I think I need to start a new VM? Do i have to? I saw several question on this site on how to do it but it's very ugly and doesn;t look robust.

Comment: I don't get why people downvote with no reason?

Comment: Most likely they have a reason in this case, but I don't get why people hit-and-run down vote and don't give a reason.

Comment: If you want each class to run in its own console and be able to exit independently, you need a process for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `Class1`:

```java
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "start", "java", "Class2");
pb.start();
```

This is gonna start a new console and run your `Class2.java`.

You may need something different than `/c`, depends what you want, [check this out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515309/what-does-cmd-c-mean)

Comment: Yes but this is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229605/is-this-really-the-best-way-to-start-a-second-jvm-from-java-code and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480433/launch-jvm-process-from-a-java-application-use-runtime-exec and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636367/executing-a-java-application-in-a-separate-process.

Comment: @PeterLawrey apparently so. i asked how to do something and the real answer is what you said that i need a new process. as to how to create a new process it was already answered a few times before. i don't know what the site rules are for this.